# Question how to create Measure Filled by Internship

Tags: powerbi, dax, powerbi-desktop

I need to make a measure that counts by NIF those who have changed from Trainee to Graduate per month in relation to the previous month. as if it were a promotion. so when I use the filter by month using the Month column, it shows the changes that have taken place from month 4 to the filtered month. is there any way of doing this?

[table youth](https://i.stack.imgur.com/8Gbwi.png)

| MONTH | YEAR | NIF | CARREIRAYOUTH |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 4 | 2023 | 1234567 | Internship |
| 5 | 2023 | 1234567 | Graduate |
| 6 | 2023 | 1234567 | Graduate |
| 7 | 2023 | 1234567 | Graduate |
| 8 | 2023 | 1234567 | Graduate |
| 9 | 2023 | 1234567 | Graduate |
| 4 | 2023 | 2222222 | Internship |
| 5 | 2023 | 2222222 | Internship |
| 6 | 2023 | 2222222 | Internship |
| 7 | 2023 | 2222222 | Internship |
| 8 | 2023 | 2222222 | Graduate |
| 9 | 2023 | 2222222 | Graduate |
| 4 | 2023 | 5555555 | Graduate |
| 5 | 2023 | 5555555 | Graduate |
| 6 | 2023 | 5555555 | Graduate |
| 7 | 2023 | 5555555 | Graduate |
| 8 | 2023 | 5555555 | Graduate |
| 9 | 2023 | 5555555 | Graduate |
| 4 | 2023 | 6666666 | Internship |
| 5 | 2023 | 6666666 | Internship |
| 6 | 2023 | 6666666 | Internship |
| 7 | 2023 | 6666666 | Internship |
| 8 | 2023 | 6666666 | Internship |
| 9 | 2023 | 6666666 | Internship |
| 4 | 2023 | 4444444 | Internship |
| 5 | 2023 | 4444444 | Internship |
| 6 | 2023 | 4444444 | Internship |
| 7 | 2023 | 4444444 | Internship |
| 8 | 2023 | 4444444 | Internship |
| 9 | 2023 | 4444444 | Graduate |

Thank you

Answer (score 0):

Create a date column with a Calculated Column on your table with:

```
Date = DATE([YEAR], [MONTH], 1)
```

Then create the following measure:

```
Promo = 
  var grads = CALCULATETABLE(VALUES(Youth[NIF]), Youth[CARREIRAYOUTH] = "Graduate" )
  var internsPM = CALCULATETABLE(VALUES(Youth[NIF]), Youth[CARREIRAYOUTH] = "Internship", PREVIOUSMONTH(Youth[Date]) )
  var interns = CALCULATETABLE(VALUES(Youth[NIF]), Youth[CARREIRAYOUTH] = "Internship" )
  RETURN IF(
    ISINSCOPE(Youth[Date]),
    COUNTROWS(INTERSECT(grads, internsPM)),
    COUNTROWS(INTERSECT(grads, interns))
  )
```

**Note** It is encouraged to use a Date table, if you have one, then replace `PREVIOUSMONTH(Youth[Date])` with your Date table date column.

[image]